# IBM websphere portal express V 8.0 fails to install

Tags: java, installation, websphere-portal

I was trying to install Websphere portal express V 8.0 on my machine, but it fails with the following error:

**Error during "post-install configure" phase ConfigEngine.bat**

The error details as in the log file are as follows:

```
FAILURE_LOG_DIR=null

BUILD FAILED
C:\ibm_portal\portal\base\wp.db.impl\config\includes\wp.db.impl_cfg.xml:598: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\ibm_portal\ConfigEngine\config\includes\setupdb_cfg.xml:429: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\ibm_portal\ConfigEngine\config\includes\db_cfg_mgr.xml:463: exec returned: 4
```

I am installing on a windows 7 machine, any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have all the Database permissions properly set in wkplc.properties and wkplc_dbdomain.properties? Is the database installed? Do you have tables and everything in it? It should spit out an install failure log. Did you look through that?

Comment: @online_p I've selected the application server and portal express to be installed together and it said that db2 will be installed as part of the installation. When the installation failed it pointed me to a log file which I copied the failure message from. someone told me that it could be a windows user thing, my user is a network user and not a local administrator, so I'll try it with a local admin.

Comment: That could definitely cause it. Create a new admin user on the box and install as that user. Give that user DB2 admin rights. You'll have to log in as that user to start/stop portal unfortunately.

Comment: I would agree that you should install portal as an admin user otherwise portal cannot create the db user. Also ensure you run the installation programme as admin